# Using regex how can we remove period '.' from prefix's like Mr. and Mrs. but not from the end of the sentences in a big paragraph or more?

Tags: python, regex

Lang: Python. Using regex for instance if I use `remove1 = re.sub('\.(?!$)', '', text)`, it removes all periods. I am only able to remove all periods, not just prefixes. Can anyone help, please? Just put the below text for example.

`Mr. and Mrs. Jackson live up the street from us. However, Mrs. Jackson's son lives in the street parallel to us.`

Comment: What have you tried up to this point?

Comment: As I wrote above, have tried re.sub(), strip() in many different ways, but not able to achieve it. New at using regex.

Comment: We all benefit from actual code examples that demonstrate the problem instead of a  blanket statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture what you want to keep, and match the dot that you want to replace.

```
\b(Mrs?)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6ROZ8/1)

In the replacement use group 1 like `\1`

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(Mrs?)\."
s = ("Mr. and Mrs. Jackson live up the street from us. However, Mrs. Jackson's son lives in the street parallel to us.\n")
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s)

print(result)
```

Output

```
Mr and Mrs Jackson live up the street from us. However, Mrs Jackson's son lives in the street parallel to us.
```